# How to configure RPI as access point?

Tags: internet, dhcp, iptables

All my life, I've been using Adafruit tutorial on How to set PRI as access point, but in the latest release the /etc/network/interfaces file looks diffrent. After following tutorial and reboot, RPI fails to start DHCP on all interfaces. Do you know any up to date tutorial, or can you tell me how to make my RPI work? I know nothing about net, and I can't figure it myself.

Comment: Hi- What is PRI?

Comment: PRI seems to be RPI=raspberry pi

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make a

1. bridge :
   http://blog.ithasu.org/2016/10/using-a-raspberry-pi-3-as-a-wifi-access-point-and-bridge/
2. hotspot : https://github.com/pihomeserver/Kupiki-Hotspot-Script

A bridge is transparent. For the hotspot, you fall on a web interface and should use login/password. HotSpot is dedicated for hotel or other public access point.

I use the bridge behind an internet box and it works very well. I can access to every peripheral on local network (printer, ...)